# Tensorflow / object_detection / training / model_main.py / tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError:

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

According to the Github instructions (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md), I prepared TFRecord files, label map file, pipeline config file and the recommended directory structure written in the page. Then I ran the following command under Windows10 and Anaconda3(64bit) Prompt.

```
python model_main.py --pipeline_config_path='training1\\models\\model\\ssd_inception_v2_pets1.config' --model_dir='training1\\models\\model' --num_train_steps=50000 --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=1 --logtostderr
```

Here, 'ssd_inception_v2_pets1.config' is modified by me from original 'ssd_inception_v2_pets.config'.

Error messages are as follows.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "model_main.py", line 109, in <module>
        tf.app.run()
      File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\obj-detect\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
        _sys.exit(main(argv))
      File "model_main.py", line 71, in main
        FLAGS.sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples))
      File "C:\Users\Tensorflow_model_master\models-master\models-master\research\object_detection\model_lib.py", line 566, in create_estimator_and_inputs
        config_override=config_override)
      File "C:\Users\Tensorflow_model_master\models-master\models-master\research\object_detection\utils\config_util.py", line 95, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file
        proto_str = f.read()
      File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\obj-detect\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 125, in read
        self._preread_check()
      File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\obj-detect\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 85, in _preread_check
        compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
      File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\obj-detect\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
        c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: 'training1\\models\\model\\ssd_inception_v2_pets1.config' : \udc8ew\udc92肳\udc82ꂽ\udc83p\udc83X\udc82\udcaa\udc8c\udca9\udc82\udca9\udc82\udce8\udc82܂\udcb9\udc82\udcf1\udc81B
; No such process
```

The last error messages are '\udc8ew~' as it is..
Could you please help me to fix this error ?

I've already checked other's discussion and, in almost all cases, mistyping of backslash(`\`) in the directory tree in the command line might cause the error. I think my expression is correct..

I guess another possibility is a typo in ssd_inception_v2_pets1.config.
I wrote the file address as follows in the file. I don't have confidence in whether I should add 'r'(row expression), choose single quatation(') or double quotation ("), and choose backslash(`\`) or double backslash( `\\`).

```
train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: r'C:\Users\Tensorflow_model_master\models-master\models-master\research\object_detection\training1\data\train.record'
  }
  label_map_path: r'C:\Users\Tensorflow_model_master\models-master\models-master\research\object_detection\training1\data\label_map.pbtxt'
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: r'C:\Users\Tensorflow_model_master\models-master\models-master\research\object_detection\training1\data\test.record'
  }
  label_map_path: r'C:\Users\Tensorflow_model_master\models-master\models-master\research\object_detection\training1\data\label_map.pbtxt'
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me it is still the path error. To save trouble I suggest you try absolute path of the config file like this `--pipeline_config_path='C:\\Users\\Tensorflow_model_master\\blabla ...'`

Also the command should be running from the 'research' directory. 
`python object_detection\model_main.py --pipeline_config_path='C:\\Users\\Tensorflow_model_master\\models-master\\models-master\\research\\object_detection\\training1\\models\\model\\ssd_inception_v2_pets1.config' --model_dir='C:\\Users\\Tensorflow_model_master\\models-master\\models-master\\research\\object_detection\\training1\\models\\model' --num_train_steps=50000 --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=1 --logtostderr`

Comment: Thank you. I tried it,,but I got the same error message..
I wrote the follwing command.

python model_main.py --pipeline_config_path='C:\\Users\\Tensorflow_model_master\\models-master\\models-master\\research\\object_detection\\training1\\models\\model\\ssd_inception_v2_pets1.config' --model_dir='C:\\Users\\Tensorflow_model_master\\models-master\\models-master\\research\\object_detection\\training1\\models\\model' --num_train_steps=50000 --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=1 --logtostderr

Comment: Thank you, danyfang ! I found other instruction web page for Win10 environment(https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10), and I could success. In this instruction, I don't need  'r'(row expression), choose single quatation(') or double quotation ("), and choose backslash( \ ) or double backslash(  \\ ) in command line and config file.